# "this[0] is undefined" message using jQuery validate plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I've started to use the jQuery validate plugin. I was having a few issues with the display of the error messages and wanted to create a test page where I could experiment with a few things. Despite the same setup working for me yesterday, I'm now getting the follwing message:

```
this[0] is undefined
```

looking at the jQuery code, it fails in the following section (specific line highlighted):

```
valid: function() {
    if ( $(this[0]).is('form')) {
        return this.validate().form();
    } else {
        var valid = true;
        **var validator = $(this[0].form).validate();**
        this.each(function() {
            valid &= validator.element(this);
        });
        return valid;
    }
}
```

from looking at it, it must think that my validator **isn't** a form, but it is. Don't really understand what's going on. The code only fails when try to print out the result of the *valid()* method to the console. Here's my code so far. Grateful for any help.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        th {
            text-align: center;
        }
        .labelCol {
            width: 60px;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.6.1.full.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.validate.full.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#myform').validate({
                        rules: {
                            thisval: "required"
                        }
        });
        console.info($('#myform').valid());
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <form id="myform" name="myform" action="" method="post">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="2">Header Section</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="labelCol">This Title</td>
                <td class="valueCol">
                    <input type="text" name="thisval" id="thisval"
                        maxlength="45" size="45" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Your `#myform` form is not loaded when the script is executed, so `$('#myform')` doesn't match anything.  Wrap your script in a ready event handler.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(function() { // <-- add this
      $('#myform').validate({
                    rules: {
                        thisval: "required"
                    }
      });
      console.info($('#myform').valid());
   });
</script>
```

Comment: Aaah. Of course. Thanks so much. Can I just ask, in what way is what you have written "$(function() {});" different from "$(document).ready(function() {});"?

Comment: @Joe, the two syntaxes are equivalent. See [`.ready()`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/).

Comment: Read the docs you linked to. Makes sense now. Thanks again for your help :)

Answer (score 2):

Wrap your code in a document ready function such as:

```
$(function()
{

    $('#myform').validate({
                    rules: {
                        thisval: "required"
                    }
    });
    console.info($('#myform').valid());

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Same happened here. For me it was a typo in my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //START of validate
$('#reply').validate({
    rules:{
        message:{
            required: true,
            },  
        },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        var data = $("#reply").serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"ajax/scripts/msg_crt.php",
            data:data,
            success:function(data){
                alert("Loaded");
                }
            });
        }
    });
    //END of validate
  });

$(document).on('click','#send', function(){
    if($('#replay').valid()){// <--- Here is my selector typo
        $("#replay").submit(); // <--- Here is my selector typo
        }
        return false;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Im my case it happens when you miss to specify the id in form tag where you did specified in validate method.