# Jquery validation error in multiple forms

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

I have two forms in the same page. jquery.validate plugin is being loaded dynamically. Since it is loaded dynamically, validation rules are created when user clicks on submit button. The validation seems to be working fine on the first form ( form id = `form` ) but doesn't work on the second one ( form id = `#form1`).

I'm getting the following error:
`this[0] is undefined`. [This question has some solutions.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6546958/3007408) But the solutions doesn't work as my script is being loaded dynamically.

Also, most of the script is plain javascript as i have provide support to almost all browsers and i do not have control over form elements names. How to proceed with second form validation? Thanks.

```
<form id="form">
    <input type="text" name="Please%20provide%20name." />
    <input type="text" name="Please%20provide%20email." />
    <input type="text" name="%50%6C%65%61%73%65%20%70%72%6F%76%69%64%65%20%70%68%6F%6E%65%20%6E%75%6D%62%65%72%2E" data-parsley-required />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
<form id="form1">
    <input type="text" name="name" />
    <input type="text" name="email" />
    <input type="text" name="phone" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

```
"use strict";
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    // on load
    var forms_count = document.forms.length,
        i = 0;
    // find all forms in the page
    for (i; i < forms_count; i++) {
        // for each form
        var form = document.forms[i];
        if (form.addEventListener) {
            // add submit handler to validate
            form.addEventListener("submit", validateForm, false); //Modern browsers
        } else if (form.attachEvent) {
            form.attachEvent('onsubmit', validateForm); //Old IE < 9
        }
    }
    // add scripts
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
    script.setAttribute('src', "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.15.0/jquery.validate.min.js");
    document.head.appendChild(script);

    // add validation rules
    validationClasses();
});

function validationClasses() {
    var forms_count = document.forms.length,
        i = 0;
    // find all forms in the page
    for (i; i < forms_count; i++) {
        // for each form
        var form = document.forms[i];
        // get form elements
        var elements = document.getElementById(form.id).elements;
        for (var element of elements) {
            // for each element, check name field and add appropriate validation class.
            var decode_name = decodeURIComponent(element.name);
            if (decode_name.toLowerCase().match(/(name|first name)/)) {
                // matching for name field.
                element.className += " valid_name";
            }
            if (decode_name.toLowerCase().match(/(email|email address)/)) {
                // matching for email field.
                element.className += " valid_email";
            }
            if (decode_name.toLowerCase().match(/(phone|phone number)/)) {
                // matching for phone field.
                element.className += " valid_phone";
            }
        }
    }
}

function validationJQRules() {
    // custom rules
    $.validator.addMethod("mobilenumber", function(value, element) {
        return this.optional(element) || /^[0-9-+\s]+$/.test(value);
    }, "Invalid Number");

    // Define validate form rules in jquery validate
    jQuery.validator.addClassRules("valid_name", {
        required: true,
    });
    jQuery.validator.addClassRules("valid_email", {
        required: true,
        email: true
    });
    jQuery.validator.addClassRules("valid_phone", {
        required: true,
        mobilenumber: true
    });
}

function validateForm(event) {
    validationJQRules();
    var form = this,
        valid = false;

    if (!valid) {
        // stop further execution of the event if not valid.
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
        event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    } else {
        console.log("proceed with form submit.");
    }

    console.log(form.id);
    $(form.id).valid();
    console.log($(form.id).valid());
};
```

Also, any other alternate method for performing validation with injected validation scripts is very much appreciated.

Comment: Why are you inserting a jQuery vaiidation AND adding onsubmit handlers? Do one or the other

Comment: on what line do you get error?

Comment: well, currently i'm using jquery validation which can change later to some other plugin. all the scripts are going to be injected into an external webpage which may or may not have multiple forms. and the external webpage can keep on changing.

Comment: i get error whenever i submit the second form while the first form works perfectly fine and validates.

Comment: on what line do you get error? where the script stops executing? is it in your code? I doubt so, there is no this[0] or similar. Does it stop in jQuery code? or elsewhere?

Comment: $(form.id).valid() may be a problem, shouldnt it be `$("#" + form.id).valid();` ?

Comment: oh, it shows error on the jquery.validate plugin.

Comment: @orhor ohk, what a big stupid i am. was trying out your solution. it seems to be validating the form now, but the error still comes in the console and when i add proper inputs form and submit the form.

Comment: any way it isn't causing errors in other flow. so maybe will disregard the console error. thanks a lot @orhor you can add it as answer if you want also if can remove the console error completly then that would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$(form.id).valid() may be a problem.
Use

```
$("#" + form.id).valid();
console.log($("#" + form.id).valid());
```